# Can you wear two of the same ring?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can a character have on two identical rings, one in each ring slot? I can't seem to find any rule saying this isn't possible, but the DM thinks it may not be. The ring I have in mind is just a pair of +1 protection rings.

Answer (score 27):

You can wear them, but their effects might not stack.

In this case, two rings of protection won't stack, because the rings provide a deflection bonus to AC, but [deflection bonuses don't stack with other deflection bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus-Deflection-).

Comment: Now rings that give you a dodge bonus to AC...

Comment: There's another reason they wouldn't stack; in 3.X, Pathfinder, and 4e, bonuses from sources of the same name *never* stack - so, for example, two Haste spells won't double the dodge bonus to your armor class.

Comment: Note, however, that while the lack of stacking bonuses does make most rings nearly worthless to double up on, there are a few exceptions. A Ring of Friend Shield, for example, doubled up on the end of the guy who soaks damage well, will allow him to protect 2 squishy allies at once by redirecting to himself half the damage due to each of them. Also, even non-stacking effects, such as your rings of protection, still provide slightly more benefit than none at all, since you're somewhat hedged against enemies who target one of them to suppress (with Dispel Magic or the like).

Comment: Hmm, Now Im wondering about Rings of Wizardry, would each one grant you the spells?

Comment: @Fering This might be a good, separate question for the site. Do a quick search first to see if it isn't already answered.

Comment: @Fering I, for one, would rule that two Rings of Wizardry of the same level probably would not, but two of different levels would.

Answer (score 16):

There is no reason you can't but it won't be any better than using just one as like bonuses don't stack:

From the [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus-Deflection-):

> Bonuses are numerical values that are added to checks and statistical scores. Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of the same type are not cumulative (do not “stack”)—only the greater bonus granted applies.

So you'd only get a +1 bonus regardless of whether you are wearing 1 or 2 rings.

Answer (score 2):

As the above says about two like bonuses, however there is an advantage to having two of the same ring if they have charges or some other use limit.  So I wouldn't mind having two rings of Fireball, each with a 1/day use limit or some-such.